# A bit confused with super() call

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

From https://realpython.com/python-super/, an example is given how super() is used to initialize the parent class. 
Code example:

```
class Rectangle:
def __init__(self, length, width):
    self.length = length
    self.width = width

def area(self):
    return self.length * self.width

def perimeter(self):
    return 2 * self.length + 2 * self.width

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)
```

> `super()` to call the `__init__()` of the Rectangle class, allowing you to use it in the Square class without repeating code.

Although, if I define Square class as such:

```
class Square(Rectangle):
    pass
```

I can use all the parent's method by instantiating an object:

```
square = Square(4,4)
```

Calling square.area outputs 16 as expected.

In the book *Python 3 Object Oriented Programming* by P. Dusty, the explanation is better (p.71):

> [...] it is possible for a superclass to go uninitialized if we neglect to explicitly call the initializer.

In the case of multiple inheritance from a single parent class, the author mentions that:

> the possibility of a superclass being called multiple times, because of the organization of the class hierarchy

I understand the latter point which is explained with an example showing that an identical method name can be called multiple times in the case of multiple inheritance. However, one can wonder in the case of simple inheritance if this would really cause trouble. Also, I don't see how the parent class couldn't be initialized...

Comment: Sure, if you don't override `__init__`, you can do `Square(4, 4)`, but then you can also do `Square(4, 5)`, and that's not square.

Comment: Ok gotcha! So you're actually obligated to call super().__init__ if you have a method .__init__ in the child class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
class Square(Rectangle):
    pass
```

Then `Square.__init__` will resolves to `Rectangle.__init__` because `Square` is not overriding it. You only have to call the super's class when you override a specific method and wants to call it for the base class.